# OOP composition and orm

Tags: database, oop, orm, dao, composition

I am building a simple rate limiter to train my oop skills and I am having some doubts regarding composition and orm.
I have the following code:

```
interface RateLimiterService {

void hit(String userid, long timestamp) throws UserDoesNotExistEx, TooManyHitsEx; // Option A

SingleRateLimiter getUser(String userid) throws UserDoesNotExistEx; // Option B

Optional<SingleRateLimiter> getUser(String userid); // Option C

}

class LocalRateLimiterService implements RateLimiterService {
    // Uses an hash table userid -> SingleRateLimiter
}

interface SingleRateLimiter {
   void hit(long timestamp) throws TooManyHitsEx;
}

class TimestampListSRL implements SingleRateLimiter {
   // Uses a list to store the timestamps and purges the expired ones at each call
}

class TokenBucketSRL implements SingleRateLimiter {
   // Uses the token bucket aproach
}
```

My doubts are:

1. Which option should I use for the RateLimiterService interface?

   - Option A is usually called "method forwarding" or "delegation" or "Law of Demeter". It protects the composed object by only exposing the intended methods and/or by possibly adding some extra validation logic before forwarding the call. Therefore, it seems like a good solution when that is needed. However, when this is not the case (as in my example), this option creates a lot of redundant repetitions which add nothing usefull.
   - Option B breaks encapsulation in a way but it avoids method repetions (the DRY principle). By picking A or B you always end up breaking some well known principles/good practices. Is there another option?
   - Option C is the same as B but returns an optional instead of throwing an exception. Which approach is considered better?
2. If the classes that implement the RateLimiterService had a single composing SingleRateLimiter instead of a collection of SingleRateLimiters (doesn't make much sense in this case but trying to be generic to other situations when the composed object is not a colection), would the best Option change to other alternative from the one in 1.?
3. If I wanted to add a database to this system, what would be the best approach to "talk to" the database?

   - creating a class DBRateLimiterService that implements RateLimiterService and has a private connection object to the database (is basically a DAO)? In this case, this class does not know anything besides the userid of the inner SingleRateLimiters, since there are multiple implementations available/possible. So how can I do this approach without changing the current OOP architecture?
   - In addition, I would need to create a DAO for each SingleRateLimiter implementation too, right? In this case, the SingleRateLimiter is not a simple model object that has only getters and setters so it should also be a DAO, right? Its hit method must be implemented as a transaction in most cases (if not all). If this is the right approach, how can the two DAOs operate together and map to the same database table?
   - What other options could serve for this?